# Logical conjunction of an indeterminate number of statments

Tags: logic

Is there an operator synonymous with the operator $$\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$$

in logic?

I.e. Let $P_i$ be a statement and let $I$ be an index set. Then,

$$\bigwedge_{i \in I} P_i$$

is the logical conjunction of several statements indexed by $I$.

(I guess my question is really whether or not this is a commonly used notation).

Thanks!

Comment: It is, definitely.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks very much.

Comment: Of course, certain restrictions apply. In first-order logic you can only have a conjunction of finitely many formulae.

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to know whether or not this is a commonly used notation since I'm new to this area :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Strangely enough, the first few articles I looked up on wikipedia, expecting to see it, didn't use the notation, but almost all logic textbooks do use it.

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps I'll widen my reading beyond Wikipedia before asking a question in MS next time.

Comment: Haha not your fault. By the way, it's also interesting that LaTeX has `\land` and `\lor` for Logical And and Or, which look exactly the same as `\wedge` and `\vee`, which are usually used for Meet and Join or other things like Wedge product, but LaTeX does **not** have `\bigland` or `\biglor` unlike `\bigwedge` and `\bigvee`!

Comment: Discriminatory typesetting language. An outrage!